# Airflow - Script does not execute when triggered

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have a airflow script that tries to insert data from one table to another, I am using a Amazon Redshift DB. The given below script when triggered does not execute. Task_id status remains as 'no status' in the Graph view and no other error is shown.

```
## Third party Library Imports

import psycopg2
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import io


# Following are defaults which can be overridden later on
default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2017, 1, 23, 12),
'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
'email_on_failure': False,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG('sample_dag', default_args=default_args, catchup=False, schedule_interval="@once")


#######################
## Login to DB

def db_login():
    global db_conn
    try:
        db_conn = psycopg2.connect(
        " dbname = 'name' user = 'user' password = 'pass' host = 'host' port = '5439' sslmode = 'require' ")
    except:
        print("I am unable to connect to the database.")
        print('Connection Task Complete: Connected to DB')
        return (db_conn)


#######################

def insert_data():
    cur = db_conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("""insert into tbl_1 select id,bill_no,status from tbl_2 limit 2 ;""")
    db_conn.commit()
    print('ETL Task Complete')

def job_run():
    db_login()
    insert_data()

##########################################

t1 = PythonOperator(
task_id='DBConnect',
python_callable=job_run,
bash_command='python3 ~/airflow/dags/sample.py',
dag=dag)

t1
```

Could anyone assist to find where the problem could be. Thanks

**Updated Code (05/28)**

```
## Third party Library Imports

import psycopg2
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
#from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import io


# Following are defaults which can be overridden later on
default_args = {
'owner': 'airflow',
'depends_on_past': False,
'start_date': datetime(2018, 1, 23, 12),
'email': ['airflow@airflow.com'],
'email_on_failure': False,
'email_on_retry': False,
'retries': 1,
'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
}

dag = DAG('sample_dag', default_args=default_args, catchup=False, schedule_interval="@once")


#######################
## Login to DB


def data_warehouse_login():
    global dwh_connection
    try:
        dwh_connection = psycopg2.connect(
        " dbname = 'name' user = 'user' password = 'pass' host = 'host' port = 'port' sslmode = 'require' ")
    except:
        print("Connection Failed.")
        print('Connected successfully')
    return (dwh_connection)

def insert_data():
    cur = dwh_connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("""insert into tbl_1 select id,bill_no,status from tbl_2 limit 2;""")
    dwh_connection.commit()
    print('Task Complete: Insert success')


def job_run():
    data_warehouse_login()
    insert_data()



##########################################

t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='DWH_Connect',
    python_callable=job_run(),
    # bash_command='python3 ~/airflow/dags/sample.py',
    dag=dag)

t1
```

**Log message when running the script**

```
[2018-05-28 11:36:45,300] {jobs.py:343} DagFileProcessor26 INFO - Started process (PID=26489) to work on /Users/user/airflow/dags/sample.py
[2018-05-28 11:36:45,306] {jobs.py:534} DagFileProcessor26 ERROR - Cannot use more than 1 thread when using sqlite. Setting max_threads to 1
[2018-05-28 11:36:45,310] {jobs.py:1521} DagFileProcessor26 INFO - Processing file /Users/user/airflow/dags/sample.py for tasks to queue
[2018-05-28 11:36:45,310] {models.py:167} DagFileProcessor26 INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /Users/user/airflow/dags/sample.py
/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
Task Complete: Insert success
[2018-05-28 11:36:50,964] {jobs.py:1535} DagFileProcessor26 INFO - DAG(s) dict_keys(['latest_only', 'example_python_operator', 'test_utils', 'example_bash_operator', 'example_short_circuit_operator', 'example_branch_operator', 'tutorial', 'example_passing_params_via_test_command', 'latest_only_with_trigger', 'example_xcom', 'example_http_operator', 'example_skip_dag', 'example_trigger_target_dag', 'example_branch_dop_operator_v3', 'example_subdag_operator', 'example_subdag_operator.section-1', 'example_subdag_operator.section-2', 'example_trigger_controller_dag', 'insert_data2']) retrieved from /Users/user/airflow/dags/sample.py
[2018-05-28 11:36:51,159] {jobs.py:1169} DagFileProcessor26 INFO - Processing example_subdag_operator
[2018-05-28 11:36:51,167] {jobs.py:566} DagFileProcessor26 INFO - Skipping SLA check for <DAG: example_subdag_operator> because no tasks in DAG have SLAs
[2018-05-28 11:36:51,170] {jobs.py:1169} DagFileProcessor26 INFO - Processing sample_dag
[2018-05-28 11:36:51,174] {jobs.py:354} DagFileProcessor26 ERROR - Got an exception! Propagating...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 346, in helper
pickle_dags)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 53, in wrapper
result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1581, in process_file
self._process_dags(dagbag, dags, ti_keys_to_schedule)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 1171, in _process_dags
dag_run = self.create_dag_run(dag)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 53, in wrapper
result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/jobs.py", line 776, in create_dag_run
if next_start <= now:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

[image: View of the Airflow UI - Graph View]

Log from the Graph View

*** Log file isn't local.
*** Fetching here: http://:8793/log/sample_dag/DWH_Connect/2018-05-28T12:23:57.595234
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker.

*** Reading remote logs...
*** Unsupported remote log location.

Comment: @tobi6, i have merged both the functions into one function and still the same problem where nothing happens when the job is triggered.. Have edited the first post with the updated code..Tnx

Comment: @darkhorse Have you turned on the dag in airflow UI?

Comment: @Chengzhi, yes the dag is turned on in the UI

Comment: why you have `bash_command='python3 ~/airflow/dags/sample.py'` in PythonOperator? I'd suggest you run `python your_dag_file.py` to figure out any compile error?

Comment: @Chengzhi, given is the error it threw when I ran the python dag_file.py

[2018-05-26 00:30:30,936] {__init__.py:57} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py:1927: PendingDeprecationWarning: Invalid arguments were passed to PythonOperator. Support for passing such arguments will be dropped in Airflow 2.0. Invalid arguments were:
*args: ()
**kwargs: {'bash_command': 'python3 ~/airflow/dags/sample.py'}
  category=PendingDeprecationWarning

Comment: You dag file is not correct that's why airflow won't schedule it for you. As it said:Invalid arguments were: *args: () **kwargs: {'bash_command': 'python3 ~/airflow/dags/sample.py'} , since you are using PythonOperator, there is no bash_command which is only available in BashOperator. Don't mix use them, if you want to run bash command, please use correct dependencies in airflow and correct operator.

Comment: @Chengzhi, I have modified the script to and if I do "python dag_file.py" it runs as expected. However the problem I have is the script runs on the background during airflow initialization. How could I modify this to run only when scheduled or triggered.. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a `PythonOperator` you need to have a `BashOperator` and a `PythonOperator`.

You are getting the error because `PythonOperator` doesn't have a `bash_command` argument

```py
t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='DBConnect',
    python_callable=db_login,
    dag=dag
    )

t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='Run Python File',
    bash_command='python3 ~/airflow/dags/sample.py',
    dag=dag
    )

t1 >> t2
```

Comment: @tobi6 agreed. @dark-horse if the `sample.py` is a DAG file you don't require this call. But if it is a normal python script you want to execute you would still use `BashOperator` to run the python file.

Comment: @tobi6, thanks for all your input. I have modified the script as per your instructions. If I try "python sample.py" the script does as per expected. However the problem I have is, the script keeps on executing on the background while initialization.. How could I avoid this and only have the script run if triggered or scheduled. Thanks..

Comment: @kaxil  , thanks for all your input. I have modified the script as per your instructions. If I try "python sample.py" the script does as per expected. However the problem I have is, the script keeps on executing on the background while initialization.. How could I avoid this and only have the script run if triggered or scheduled. Thanks..

Comment: is the `sample.py` file a DAG file or a python script?

Comment: @kaxil, its a DAG file (File name : sample.py). I have included the modifed query in my first message in this post (Labelled : Updated code : 05/28). Tnx..

Comment: @tobi6, I have updated my initial message with the updated code (Labelled : Updated code : 05/28). Have also pasted the log generated (Log message when running the script) when triggering the script in my initial message. Could you please advice tnx..

Comment: @tobi6, what I mean by "Log message when running the script" is. If I run the above Dag code (Python file) in a IDLE (I am using Pycharm), it executes as expected. However, if I try to run this using the Airflow, when I initiate airflow (airflow initdb) and start webserver (airflow webserver -p 8080), the code keeps running in the background and the output is exectued and reflects in the DB. But I have niether triggered it or scheduled it to run and hence I am not sure why this happens without me defining / scheduling the jobs. Hope this clarifies..

Answer (score 1):

To the answer kaxil provided I would like to extend that you should be using an IDE to develop for Airflow. PyCharm works fine for me.

That being said, please make sure to look up the available fields in the docs next time. For PythonOperator, see the docs here:

https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.operators.PythonOperator

Signature looks like:

> class airflow.operators.PythonOperator(**python_callable**, op_args=None, op_kwargs=None, provide_context=False, templates_dict=None, templates_exts=None, *args, **kwargs)

and for BashOperator, see the docs here:

https://airflow.apache.org/code.html#airflow.operators.BashOperator

Signature is:

> class airflow.operators.BashOperator(**bash_command**, xcom_push=False, env=None, output_encoding='utf-8', *args, **kwargs)

Highlights are from me to show the parameters you have been using.

Make sure to dig through the documentation a bit before using an Operator is my recommendation.

**EDIT**

After seeing the code update there is one thing left:

Make sure when defining `python_callable` in a task that you do so without brackets, otherwise the code will be called (which is very unintuitive if you don't know about it). So your code should look like this:

```
t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='DWH_Connect',
    python_callable=job_run,
    dag=dag)
```

Comment: sorry I overlooked this as you had mentioned earlier. I have made that change and triggered the job again. Could you please check the logs attached in the initial message. I have triggered the job and see task_id in "no status" and isn't changing. Thnx.

Comment: I am referring to the "Airflow UI - Graph view" which shows the current status. I have attached a view of the **Graph view** in the initial message.

Comment: On clicking DWH_Connect Task_id and logs I see the below message

*** Log file isn't local.
*** Fetching here: http://:8793/log/sample_dag/DWH_Connect/2018-05-28T12:23:57.595234
*** Failed to fetch log file from worker.

*** Reading remote logs...
*** Unsupported remote log location.

Comment: You should ask another question since this seems to be a configuration issue regarding to your log which is different from the initial question. Usually it is one question and not multiple ones like a support chat ;)

Comment: Sorry will do.. Thanks for all your support :)

Comment: one quick question. I tried to run each of the above two functions separately. Namely  db_login() and insert_data().

db_login() executed properly but insert_data() failed and the error message was "NameError: name 'dwh_connection' is not defined". Since i have passed the login details as a global connection why does it fail when I re-use it. Any advice on this. Thnx..

Comment: @darkhorse Please ask another question for this. I will provide an answer there.